# Unity Prevent game objects from resizing when resolution changes

Tags: resize, resolution

I have a rectangle sprite that animates when a score is reached. Starts offscreen and then move onscreen before moving off-screen again. Works fine. Problem is when I change the resolution for different devices the sprite resizes and doesn't display as intended. The text fields inside the rectangle move outside on some of the resolutions. How can i keep the sprite at the original size regardless of resolution. I have tried Preserve Aspect, Set Native Size, moving anchors but it still resizes. I also tried using a panel.Any Ideas?

Comment: You should probably share the hierarchy.

Comment: Have you tried 'Canvas Scaler'  -> 'UI Scale Mode'  to 'Scale with screen size'.

Comment: I need the Canvas Scaler to "Scale with screen size" for all my other UI elements but I don't want this to scale with screen size. I tried creating a new canvas inside the main canvas and putting this element inside the new canvas  because a "non-root canvas will not be scaled". That came close to working but not on all resolutions. Still baffled.Thanks for the answers.